# VS code extension for knowing where function is called from

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I want VScode to inform where a defined function is being called from.

file utils.js

```
function counter(){
 console.log('counter');
}
export default counter;
```

file index.js:

```
import counter from './utils';

counter();
```

I want to know in counter function definition in utils.js that it is being used at index.js

if the function counter is called in different files I want to get the information about where the function is being used | called from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. I found that VScode has an inbuilt reference locater.  Just right-click the function and select the option find all references, and VScode will locate all the references to that functions Shortcut: Alt + Shift + F12

Answer (score 2):

As stated by *@hUwUtao*, the callstack has the information about the callers of your `counter()` function when it is executing.  If you want to find references without executing, VS Code can do this by right-clicking the function, then selecting **Go to References**, as seen in the following screenshot.

[image: VS Code Option Go to References]

Comment: i think this works in single page only. I want all function calls from different files where that function is imported and called

Comment: Because we usually work in modules, I suppose you get the references on the variable that does the importing of the module.  I think understand now.

Comment: I am sorry sir but it doesn't work. I am developing something in reactjs as it doesn't work here. I saw something like that in java codes and wanted the same thing. I just want where the function is being imported and called.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Explain: Browser log should show the whole callstack where the error should throw

Comment: I don't want where the error should throw, I want where the function is being called from

Comment: @AnishShrestha The underlined blue text should tell
(sorry too lazy to put those code in a file :( )